# Flutter : Gradle build failed

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter app works fine on IOS, but I get a gradle build failure when I try to run on Android. This is error log:

Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
>   The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.1,16.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Any ways to resolve this issue ? Thanks !

Comment: A possible workaround https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19868#issuecomment-408550356, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18579#issuecomment-398529653

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that workaround and it works, great but thought this issue might be resolved correctly instead of a a quick fix ?

Comment: Did you see the 2nd link. I added it a bit after I posted the initial comment (about minute 17:00)